# Как получить строки, добавленные за последние 5 секунд

Tags: sql, postgresql

Для MSSQL запрос выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен аналогичный запрос для postgresql, который будет выводить строки за последние 5 секунд

В таблице есть поле date, в котором содержится время добавления строки

Comment: `WHERE timestamp_field > current_timestamp - interval '5 seconds'`

Comment: Не знаю что там за задача, но если задача регулярно вычитывать свежие записи, то это неправильный подход.

Comment: Согласен с коллегой. Даже если вы вычитываете записи в гарантированно детерминированной среде без учета сбоев было принято считать что время реакции системы равно удвоенному времени дискретизации. Это значит что в общем случае что бы снизить вероятность потерянных данных время опроса должно быть в два раза меньше времени захвата и это в идеальных условиях. Такие подходы используются в аппаратных средах на основе каруселей, в СУБД видимо все таки нужно использовать отказоустойчивые очереди на уровне доменной бизнес-логики.